# Who sits next to Senate party leaders when they speak?

Tags: united-states, senate

[image: Screencap of Chuck Schumer speaking with a woman to his left]
[image: Picture of Mitch McConnell speaking with a woman to his right]

They seem not to be Senators. Who are they?

Comment: "They seem not to be senators" based on what, exactly?

Comment: Funnily, most Senators (including Schumer) did not respond to a PBS question as to the identity of the aide sitting behind them in speeches. https://www.pbs.org/newshour/politics/whos-behind-the-senator

Comment: I'm VTCing this question as the prototypical "too broad" question. The answer below is half-good, half-bad as alas is typical of such questions.

Answer (score 6):

They are not Senators but rather [Senate-elected officers](http://www.senate.gov/senators/leadership.htm).

The person in the 1st picture seems to be the **Secretary of the Senate**, [Julie E. Adams](https://www.senate.gov/reference/common/person/julie_adams.htm).

[image: Image 1]

While the person in the 2nd picture is the **Secretary for the Majority**, [Laura Dove](https://www.senate.gov/reference/common/person/dove_laura.htm).

[image: Image 2]

*Photos from http://www.senate.gov/senators/leadership.htm.*

Comment: The person int he 1st picture does not seem to be the Secretary of the Senate. I think the person is probably a staff member of the Schumer team.

Comment: Here is a clearer screenshot from today's Russian diplomat meeting speech http://i.imgur.com/BxO8vRn.png

Comment: I'm also pretty sure it's not Adams sitting behind Schumer. You can see a better photo of Adams in https://ussenateyouth.org/leaders-behind-the-scenes-senate-secretary-julie-adams/

Answer (score 3):

The woman to the right of Schumer is his deputy chief of staff, Erin Sager Vaughn

Comment: Welcome to Politics.SE! Could you add a link to a source where we can see Ms Vaughn for comparison?