# Who is sitting behind Chuck Schumer?

Tags: united-states, senate, trump-impeachment

Who is this blonde with the glasses behind Chuck Schumer? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: what does this have to do with politics?

Comment: Presumably the person is a political figure of some kind, and may have some role in the Senate

Comment: My guess is it is an aide. Senators have a veritable army.

Comment: There's a [2017 story](https://www.politico.com/story/2017/01/senate-schumer-233047) listing some names of Schumer's aides, but I'm not getting a photo match with any of those, so it's probably someone not mentioned in that article.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who sits next to Senate party leaders when they speak?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/19001/who-sits-next-to-senate-party-leaders-when-they-speak)

Comment: Hi Chipster, Yes that who I'm referring too, however the person they claim it is, is not that person. Thank you for your help